# jquery on handler not working for inserted element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler

I've got a simple to-do list app. To-do items are inserted by jQuery as `<li>` items. When they're checked off, they're removed from `#todolist` and prepended to `#donelist`. I want to let the user replace to-do items they've accidentally checked off, hence the `.on` handler for `#donelist .checkbox` elements, but it's not working. I've been puzzling over this for an embarrassingly long amount of time. How can I get the click handler working for `#donelist .checkbox`es?

HTML:

```
<div id="topform">
    <input type="text" id="task" placeholder=" New task...">
</div>

<ul id="todolist">

</ul>

<ul id="donelist">

</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#todolist').on('click', '.checkbox', checkTask);
$('#donelist').on('click', '.checkbox', replaceTask);

$('input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
    addTask(e);
    }
});

function addTask(e) {
    taskToAdd = $('#task').val();
    var listItem = "<li><span class='todotask'>" + taskToAdd + "</span><div class='checkbox'></div></li>";
    $('#todolist').prepend(listItem);
}

function checkTask() {
    var listItem = $(this).parent();
    listItem.remove();
    $('#donelist').prepend(listItem);
}

function replaceTask() {
    alert('hey buddy');
}
```

Full CSS:

```
html,
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #313131;
font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}

#task {
width: 98%;
margin: 5px auto 7px auto;
padding: 0;
display: block;
height: 45px;
border: none;
border-radius: 2px;
font-size: 25px;
background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

ul {
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
padding: 0;
width: 98%;
}

li {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 5px auto 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
line-height: 45px;
position: relative;
font-size: 25px;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

#donelist li {
opacity: .5;
text-decoration: line-through;
}

.todotask {
margin-left: 7px;
}

.checkbox {
height: 31px;
width: 31px;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: #C1C1C1;
position: absolute;
right: 7px;
top: 7px;
}
```

`checkTask()` works just fine, which is what really confuses me. `checkTask()` is called when the user clicks on a dynamically inserted element (a `div` in a `li` that's inserted by `addTask()`. Why doesn't `replaceTask()` fire as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the corresponding HTML in the OP would have helped, so I've had to guess a bit about how the structure, but here's a working [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yTzEA/1/) of what I think you're looking for:

**HTML**

```
<h1>ADD</h1>
<input id="task"></input>
<button id="add">Add</button>

<h1>TODO</h1>
<ul id="todolist">
    <li><span class='todotask'>" Take out the garbage "</span><div class='checkbox'></div></li>
    <li><span class='todotask'>" Do the dishes "</span><div class='checkbox'></div></li>
</ul>

<h1>DONE</h1>
<ul id="donelist">

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.checkbox{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JavaScript** *inside document.ready()*

```
$('#todolist').on('click', '.checkbox', checkTask);
$('#donelist').on('click', '.checkbox', replaceTask);
$("#add").click(addTask);


function addTask(e) {
    taskToAdd = $('#task').val();
    var listItem = "<li><span class='todotask'>" + taskToAdd + "</span><div class='checkbox'></div></li>";
    $('#todolist').prepend(listItem);
}

function checkTask() {
    var listItem = $(this).parent();
    listItem.remove();
    $('#donelist').prepend(listItem);
}

function replaceTask() {
    var listItem = $(this).parent();
    listItem.remove();
    $('#todolist').prepend(listItem)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It does exactly what I was going for, yes. But what's different? I'm not seeing what's changed (aside from the obvious fattening up of the `replaceTask` function, which just had a placeholder alert before. Was it something to do with the `.on()` handlers? They're what was confusing me so much, I think.

Comment: Honestly, the code looked correct. So unless there's perhaps a misspelled `id` or maybe the structure is a bit different in your HTML then I'm not too sure. If you wanna edit the post with your HTML I can take a look at it as well to see if I can piece it together.

Comment: I added the <body> of the HTML and more of the original JS, the keypress handler that fires everything. Thanks again. Maybe I did make a goofy spelling error somewhere...

Comment: I made a jsfiddle example with what you have posted above and from what I can tell it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7h8ra/

Are you surrounding your jQuery in the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Comment: Yep, all's in the document ready function. I must have dropped a bracket or something. I guess this is a lesson in the importance of posting full code.

Comment: No worries :D Happens to us all. Hope it's all cleared up now though and working for you. Good luck